# Cuda has unmet dependencies. Unable to install

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

I have been trying to install cuda, and I cannot for the life of me figure this out :(. This is the error that i keep running into, and I can't think of any packages that would be broken on this machine. It's a fresh install of Ubuntu Server (uname -a `Linux marte 4.18.0-11-generic #12-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 19:22:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` running Cosmic)

```
% sudo apt-get install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Some other possibly useful information?

My attempt to find any broken packages

```
% sudo debsums --changed
sudo debsums --changed  7.72s user 3.54s system 22% cpu 49.658 total
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates main universe
```

Edit: Going down the rabbit whole to try and install unmet dependencies manually, I have come to the following wall

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-410 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-23 but it is not installable
              Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 331.20) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                          bumblebee but it is not going to be installed
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In apt-speak, *dependency problems* are what 'broken' actually means. Look for *wrong-version sources* that cause the impossible situation. For example, the error message is saying that the non-Ubuntu-package `cuda-10-0` cannot be installed due to dependency problems.

Comment: @user535733 That was what I originally thought! So going down the rabbit whole, I was met with an error that I'm not entirely sure how to deal with, I've updated the original post to reflect these "findings". As per the edit, should I be looking in a non-ubuntu repo for this? Im not sure what `is not installable` means (outside of not able to be installed :'D)

Comment: Server does not even have X, so while I have seen the cuda executables run the non-graphical samples under Wayland, how are you planning on running cuda?

Comment: I swear one day i'll learn how to post @ubfan1 This was another thought I had, so I tried installing X. Are your thoughts that I should scrap it (It really is just a fresh install with X, and zsh installed) and install ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Might as well, if you need to install X on a server, desktop is probably the way to go. Get the Nvidia drivers set up from the ubuntu repos, and then do the CUDA deb from Nvidia.  Not sure what cuda you'd need from the ubuntu repos after that, maybe nothing.

Comment: Great I will try that and report back!! Thanks for the quick reply :D

Comment: @ubfan1 After setting up Ubuntu desktop, I am faced with the exact same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package that provides xorg-vide-abi-* was xserver-xorg-core(2:1.19.6-ubuntu4.2) but the held package was xserver-xorg-core(2:1.20*) and no longer provided the xerver-xorg-core package necessary

So downgrading said package worked, and ignoring said package (`sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core`) when upgrading did the trick

Answer (score 6):

the problem is that ubuntu does not know where to find these packages. type the following code in terminal:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Comment: Please go back and re-read the question this is **not** a solution to the problem, I have already provided my solution in one of the edits,

Comment: @j-money Consider to write into a proper answer instead of edit within the question itself. Yes, you can and encouraged to [self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @j-money if the problem is "cuda has unmet dependencies", i think my solution works also, and it is an easier one

Comment: While I am no longer running the server in this configuration, I can assure you that this was one of the solutions I tried which did not solve the issue at hand. In any event it is a moot point as it had been solved over 3 months ago now. When posting, pay attention to timestamps, as well as reading the **entire** question

Comment: @j-money while i am pretty sure i managed to solve this problem by this solution a couple of hours ago

Comment: @j-money It is OK to post a new answer to an already solved question! It might be useful for other users running in the same situation. You are not forced to accept or upvote the new answer.

Comment: @Melebius While I in no way disagree with you in this regard, there is no sense in having an answer that does not solve the problem. Setting up a vm with the same environment I am able to reproduce the error, and this solution does not solve said error

Comment: @j-money Watch your tone. And please don't give bad advice. Timestamps are absolutely irrelevant here, answers are always welcome even on older posts. And answers that can help other users with the same (or similar) problem are also welcome. Granted, this isn't helpful for you, but that's no reason to be rude.